# Call multiple Controller in angularjs from one view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting problem in executing multiple controller for one view. I have a main index.html file in which I am displaying counts in header. For that I created a seperate Controller file "headerController" and referred in body

```
<body ng-controller="headerController">
```

Now in router provider I had routed to another controller based on URL

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'resources/assets/partials/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'});
```

By default my application lands on home page so what I want is first in header it displays the count and than runs the HomeCtrl, but right now it only displays count and does not execute Home controller.

What is the best way to handle this type of scenarios ?

Comment: It is typical for a view to have multiple controllers (each creating a child-scope). Multiple controllers can co-exist in a view (HTML page) without problem. Have you set up your `ngView` correctly ? Show the relevant parts of the code or prepare a fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: See following example: [http://jsfiddle.net/carpasse/mcVfK/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/carpasse/mcVfK/3/)

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way is to use Razor
and you need to to something like this

```
public ActionResult Home(string Name)
    {
        if (Name == "/home")
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home";
            ViewBag.Form = "resources/assets/partials/home.html";
            ViewBag.Controller = "HomeCtrl";
        }
```

}